# AngularJS Promises: Put promise in Factory so it is globally accessible and *editable*

Tags: angularjs, promise, factory

I'm trying to pull data from an external JSON file and display it for the user to see. Through various actions, the user would then be able to change the data returned from the JSON file, without writing those changes to the file (in this example, incrementing values by one by clicking on a div). I've created a promise service that successfully pulls the data and displays it. I can even get it so the data can be changed in individual controllers.

**This is where I get stuck:** I cannot find a way to make any changes to the data in the PromiseService, so changes cannot propagate globally. How do I make it that any change in the promise data at the controller level will be reflected in the PromiseService and, thus, reflected in any data binding in the app? I'm new to promises, so I'm open to a completely different approach.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/34EQoYzxeCtqLyDUB6sW?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="pageApp" ng-controller="pageCtrl" nd-model="items">
    {{items}}
    <div class="button" ng-controller="buttonCtrl" ng-click="incrementValues()">
        Click to increment:
        <br>{{items}}
    </div>
</body>
```

PromiseService:

```
pageApp.factory('PromiseService', function($http) { 
    var getPromise = function() {
        return $http.get('items.json').then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };

    return {
        getPromise: getPromise
    };
});
```

Button Controller (Page Controller in Plunker):

```
pageApp.controller('buttonCtrl', function($scope, PromiseService) {
    $scope.incrementValues = function()
    {
        PromiseService.getPromise().then(function(data) {
            $scope.items = data;
            for(var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++)
            {
                data.items[i]['value']++;
            }
        }).catch(function() {
        });
    };
});
```

The incrementValues function works successfully the first time, but each consecutive click re-pulls the promise and resets the data. To sum up: how do I reflect the incremented values in the PromiseService, as opposed to local variables?

Comment: What do you want is to retrieve the data, once it gets done update that data in different controllers without retrieving the data again?

Comment: @ManuelObregozo - that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function creates a new $http call every time it's called, and thus returns a new promise, encspsulating new data, every time it's called.

You need to return the same promise every time:

```
var thePromise = $http.get('items.json').then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
});

var getPromise = function() {
    return thePromise;
};
```

Comment: I updated the PromiseService factory to reflect your changes [in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FUuYfPyPDq8aCYTOydBB?p=preview). I was unsure if it should be called in the controller as a promise or a regular object; I tried both and neither worked. I can't seem to get any data out of the PromiseService now.

Comment: You just need to do what I told in the answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/xvFAXbmiByezJQzPYGVz?p=preview

Comment: Ah, I had a typo somewhere. Thanks for responding! This works wonderfully.

Answer (score 2):

You could add to your factory a `private` property where you store the items. Then create 3 different methods to update and access to that property.

```
    pageApp.factory('PromiseService', function($http) { 
        var items = {}; // [] in case it is an array

        var updateData = function(updatedData){
            items = updatedData;
        }

        var getUpdateData = function(){
            return items;
        }

        var getPromise = function() {
            return $http.get('items.json').then(function(response) {
                items = response.data;
                return response.data;

            });
        };

        return {
            getPromise: getPromise,
            updateData : updateData,
            getUpdateData : getUpdateData 
        };
    });


pageApp.controller('buttonCtrl', function($scope, PromiseService) {

    $scope.items = [];

   //You should call this method to retrieve the data from the json file
   $scope.getData = function(){
        PromiseService.getPromise().then(function(data) {
            $scope.items = data;            
        }).catch(function() {
        });

   }

   $scope.incrementValues = function(){
       for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){
           $scope.items[i]['value']++;
       }     
       PromiseService.updateData($scope.items); //This could be skipped in case you do not want to 'store' these changes. 
   };
});
```

Then in others controller you could use the same service to retrieve the `updated Data` like this:

```
$scope.items = PromiService.PromiseService();
```

In the future you could also create a new method to update the json itself instead of stored internally